# Sobre o carregamento de página Jquery

Tags: jquery

Entendo o uso deste trecho de código em Jquery abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
alert("carregou");
})
```

Porém, o problema em questão é que, quando carrego algo por iframe, essa função não é executada novamente, **como faço para detectar quando um iframe é carregado?**

Inicialmente, ao entrar na página, o iframe não é exibido, a função acima cumpre, alertando quando o html dá pagina é carregado, mas a pessoa pode escolher entre as opções da tela, e assim irá abrir um iframe em qualquer opção escolhida, porém não é exibida a mensagem de "carregou" quando o iframe termina o carregamento.. 
Enfim, a questão é:

**como faço para detectar quando um iframe é carregado?**

Answer (score 2):

Sua função JavaScript está implementada para ser executada uma vez que o documento (a página, por assim dizer) esteja carregado.

Para que a função seja executada depois de um iframe ser carregado, utilize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').ready(function() {
        alert("carregou iframe");
    });
})
```

Comment: Perfeito, deu certo aqui, apenas troquei o ready por load, para que espera-se de fato a página carregar todos os recursos além da dita renderização.